# Pressure created by two equal magnitude opposing "pulling" forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, pressure, vectors, free-body-diagram

I'm trying to understand the concept of negative relative pressure found in the intrapleural space. Since I'm having trouble with the physics part, I thought I'd ask here.
The idea is this: imagine a bag (pleura) that it's interior linings are attached inside, like a deflated bag. There is a very small amount of liquid inside. It is being pulled from opposing sides by forces that are equal in magnitude (lungs against chest wall). Text books say this will create a negative relative pressure (to the atmospheric pressure). Reference at the bottom from berne & levy physiology 7th edition.
What I'm thinking is: to my knowledge, measuring pressure is done by checking how much force is applied on a given surface. How will this scenario decrease the pressure measured?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you situation correctly, you are increasing the size of a sealed bag. The volume increases, and hence, from the ideal gas law (i.e. pressure times volume is constant), you can expect that the pressure decreases, hence it is lower than atmospheric pressure.

I am not sure how measuring the pressure comes in here? It depends on the type of sensor you are using, but that the relative pressure is negative is not a problem per se.